# Why would a ContentProvider query which should return results return 0 rows?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I use a ContentProvider in my app.  I'm attempting to do a query with the following code:

```
String where = MyColumns.USER_ID + " = ?"
        + " and " + MyColumns.DAY + " >= ?"
        + " and " + MyColumns.DAY + " < ?"
        + " and " + MyColumns.STATUS + " <> ?";

Cursor mycursor = getContentResolver().query(DbDefinitions.URI_MY_TABLE,
                    MyColumns.getDisplayColumns(),
                    where,
                    new String[] {
                        String.valueOf(params.mUserId),
                        String.valueOf(today.getTimeInMillis()/1000L),
                        String.valueOf(tomorrow.getTimeInMillis()/1000L),
                        DbDefinitions.STATE_DELETING
                    },
                    MyColumns.DAY + " asc");
```

Debugging through the ContentProvider, the Cursor object contains the following values for `mQuery.mSql` and `mQuery.mBindArgs`:

```
SELECT _id, user_id, column3, day, column5, status, column7, column8, column9
FROM my_table
WHERE user_id = ? and day >= ? and day < ? and status <> ? ORDER BY day asc;

[1691, 1386576000, 1386662400, STATE_DELETING]
```

The `mCount` is 0.

However, if I copy and paste this query into terminal (connected to the db), I get a row back:

3|1691|6|1386604595|1386597600|STATE_OK||some test text|14

Yes, they are hitting the same database.  All of the other data in the database shows up in my app.  I've just added this 1 table and the data from this table alone is not coming back in queries.

There are no exceptions during the query.

Ideas?

Comment: When you copy/paste the query, SQLite will complain about `?`. What is the actual query you tried?

Comment: I plugged the values from mBindArgs into the query.  The query I ran is: `SELECT _id, user_id, column3, day, column5, status, column7, column8, column9
FROM my_table
WHERE user_id = 1691 and day >= 1386576000 and day < 1386662400 and status <> 'STATE_DELETING' ORDER BY day asc;`.  This returns a row (as it should).  However, the `Cursor` object contains no rows using the above `mQuery.mSql` and `mQuery.mBindArgs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem.  When I created the table, I did not specify a column type on the "day" column.  Apparently, sqlite3 lets you get away with this.  I assume it defaults to a text column

`..., day not null, ...`

Comment: All your parameters are converted to strings. You should not use parameters for plain integers.

Comment: Right.  To expand, when a column is created and no type is specified, I believe it defaults to a blob.  When I "copied" the query and ran it, I did not wrap the day values in quotes.  Thus, a row was returned.